# Foundation 4 Top-bar Nav Not Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm experiencing a bizarre error when trying to implement Foundation's (4.1.1) top-bar nav menu. On the local server, the menu works fine on desktop & mobile - it's properly compressed, the menu button works, and the menu items drop down.

But in the production environment (on Heroku), I'm getting this error that points to a line of js.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cookie' of undefined
```

To my knowledge, the JS files are compiled in the proper order in the application.js file.